# Error while creating array in Google Colab

Tags: python, arrays, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create a database that I will later split using "train_test_split()" into a set of X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test. I thought it would be best to create an array containing a dictionary of data.
I am getting an error when trying to create an array in Google Colab:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6d46d202b3e5> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import array
----> 2 array1 = {'data': array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]), 'target': array([101, 102, 103, 104])}

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am attaching the program code below:

import array

array1 = {'data': array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]), 'target': array([101, 102, 103, 104])}

Comment: `array.array`, but it won't work either since it can't handle 2D lists. What are you trying to do? do you really need to use `array`?

Comment: Do you need `np.array` ?

Comment: I'm trying to create a database that I will later split using "train_test_split()" into a set of X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test. I thought it would be best to create an array containing a dictionary of data.

Comment: Use `numpy` array than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how to create arrays in Python. It seems like you are trying to create a dictionary (array1) with two keys, 'data' and 'target', where the values associated with these keys are supposed to be NumPy arrays. However, you are using the array module incorrectly, which is leading to the error.

To create NumPy arrays, you should use the NumPy library, not the array module. Here's how you can fix your code:

```
import numpy as np

data_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
target_array = np.array([101, 102, 103, 104])

array1 = {'data': data_array, 'target': target_array}
```